# An unhandled exception occured. Não consigo entender essa mensagem, não vem detalhe algum

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Pessoal essa mensagem:

> An unhandled exception occured.

Acontece sempre quando eu tento consumir meu serviço `REST`. Eu fiz primeiramente um exemplo, copiando do **Macoratti** e deu certo. Aí adaptei para meu serviço e não funcionou, dando esse erro. Estou revendo o projeto do **Macoratti** e mesmo assim, não funciona. Sempre que chega nessa linha não funciona: `var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);`. O problema é que a mensagem de erro não tem mais nada, nenhum **Inner Exception**, detalhes, nada, apenas a mensagem.
Esse é meu DataService(Mantive até o nome da classe)

```
public class DataService
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public async Task<List<LiberacaoDTO>> GetLiberaAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "http://localhost:9078/api/liberacao";
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var liberacao = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiberacaoDTO>>(response);
                return liberacao;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Esse é o meu MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        DataService dataService;
        List<LiberacaoDTO> libera;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataService = new DataService();
            AtualizaDados();
        }
        async void AtualizaDados()
        {
            libera = await dataService.GetLiberaAsync();
            listaLibera.ItemsSource = libera.OrderBy(item => item.Cliente).ToList();
        }

        private void listaLibera_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var libera = e.SelectedItem as LiberacaoDTO;

            txtNome.Text = libera.Cliente;
            txtCategoria.Text = libera.Vendedor;
            txtPreco.Text = libera.Juros.ToString();
        }
    }
```

O MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Autorizador"
             x:Class="Autorizador.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,0,0">
            <Label Text="Adicionar um Produto" TextColor="Green" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Label x:Name="txtNome" Text="Nome do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label x:Name="txtCategoria" Text="Categoria do Produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label x:Name="txtPreco" Text="Preço do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                    HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <!--<Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Adicionar/Atualizar Produto" 
                    Clicked="btnAdicionar_Clicked" FontSize="Small"/>-->
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,5,10,0">
            <ListView x:Name="listaLibera" ItemSelected="listaLibera_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Cliente}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Vendedor}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Juros}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

O App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //MainPage = new Autorizador.MainPage();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Autorizador.MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Criei uma classe semelhante à classe do meu serviço. Inclusive mantive exatamente o mesmo nome, LiberacaoDTO. Apesar do nome DTO, neste projeto é apenas um nome mesmo, só para manter a semelhança ou igualdade, como queiram.

```
public class LiberacaoDTO
    {
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        public string DataLib { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        public string Juros { get; set; }
        public string Desconto { get; set; }
        public string Vencimento { get; set; }
        public string Acrescimo { get; set; }
        public string Entrada { get; set; }
        public decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    }
```

Eu faço assim: Abro duas instâncias do VS2017, uma para o serviço e outra para o App. Então, o serviço está rodando, não seria esse o problema.

**EDIT1**
Screenshot da mensagem de erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta é a mensagem pega no catch: `An error occurred while sending the request`

Comment: Essa exceção esta caindo dentro do catch? Normalmente exceções sem descrição são exceções da própria ferramenta do visual studio. Exemplo: Eu já refatorei uma implementação tão pesada, que se requisitada várias vezes quebrada o stack de execução do visual studio.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, não cara, não coloquei num bloco `try..catch`. Seria ideal, tratar a exception, certo? Mas, qual o tipo de exception a ser tratada? Eu não sei o que tratar. Se colocar uma Exception genérica, vai cair na mesma mensagem.

Comment: Cara seu código esta quebrando dentro de um try..catch, não notou? Se ele esta em um try..catch, e não foi pego, esse é um erro da ferramenta interna do visual studio. Note que sua aplicação é até pausada por causa da exception. Vai ser difícil de resolver esse erro, pode ser muita coisa.

Comment: @GabrielColetta, eu sei, da forma como está dá pau e não entra, porem se eu der `throw new exception...` e coloco um **break** no `catch`, consigo pegar a exception que é essa: `An error occurred while sending the request`

Answer (score 2):

Tenta enviar uma solicitação para a url (http://localhost:9078/api/liberacao) usando algum cliente http (por exmplo esse: https://www.getpostman.com/). Pode dar uma pista sobre qual o problema que está dando na resposta.

Comment: O serviço funciona. Pelo Postman(json) eu consigo e pelo próprio browser(xml) eu tenho dados neles. Não sei se é isso que você está sugerindo. Só não funciona dentro do App. Mas lembre-se, copiando o exemplo do Macoratti, funciona. Se mantenho o mesmo exemplo e troco apenas a Model e claro, e aponto para o meu serviço, aí dá o erro. Por isso penso ser o serviço, sei lá e como não tenho o serviço do Macoratti para comparar com o meu. Porém o meu fuunciona sem problemas, seja com Postman ou com  o Chrome e o IE.

Comment: Está funcionando agora. Vi algumas coisas que quero compartilhar. Removi todos os pacotes do xamarin e reinstalei. Vi que a minha internet estava oscilando demais e como eu estava com meu 4g desligado, isso também gerava o problema. Esse tipo de exceção, é uma exceção genérica do xamarin, que é disparada para qualquer problemas que venha a ocorrer, pelo que eu entendi. Não tem um detalhamento do que está acontecendo, apenas diz que existe um problema em algum lugar e deve ser tratado. Eventos no xaml e não implementado no behind, falta de conexão, qualquer coisa dispara essa exceção.